# Ideals of $k[[x,y]]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, formal-power-series

I have a problem

> Let $R=k[[x,y]]$ and $m$ be the maximal ideal. Let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$. Then $I$ is isomorphic to an $m$-primary ideal of $R$ as $R$-modules.

I believe it is too beautiful to be true. I don't know how to start.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you really think that $I=(x)$ is isomorphic to an $m$-primary ideal?

Comment: Let me reformulate: what tells you about $\dim R$ the existence of a principal $m$-primary ideal?

Comment: Are you suggesting me any references?

Comment: Theorem 11.14 from Atiyah and Macdonald.

Comment: I just checked and there is no way that (x) is isomorphic to a m-primary. So is the problem wrong?

Comment: All right, exclude the principal ideals. Then why all other ideals have only one prime ideal above them? m is one of them, but how can we deduce what you say just from the fact that the ideals are generated by 2 elements?

Comment: Actually one can show the following: if $I=(f,g)$ and $\gcd(f,g)=1$ then $\sqrt I=\mathfrak m$. If $\mathfrak p$ is a height one prime over $I$, then $\mathfrak p$ is principal (it must contain a prime element, say $p$, since $R$ is a UFD, and thus $\mathfrak p=(p)$) and then $f=pf_1$, $g=pg_1$, a contradiction. When $\gcd(f,g)=d$, $d\ne 1$,  then $I=dJ$ with $J$ generated by two coprime elements. (Note that all I sshowed holds in a local UFD of dimension two.)

Answer (score 1):

It might be true. If $I$ is a principal ideal, then $I\cong R$ as $R$-modules. You could try to show that every non-principal proper ideal $I$ can be written as $I=fQ$ where $Q$ is $m$-primary.

Comment: Why does this have a down vote? This does answer OPs question correctly, while $Q$ may be $m$-primary or $R$, which is not too far from what is asked.